# Need jquery or javascript function to get round up value of input number

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is my script which I am trying to find solution for it. But I actually this function return round of **ANS: 2**. Eg. If input value is greater than 2.01 then result will be 3. I know round function is not help me to get this kind of answer. please help me to fix this issue.

> `<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>`

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.round(2.01); 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: If answer helps you please mark as accepted for further use

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  user asking about javascript

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
<script>
  num = Math.ceil(2.01);
  alert(num);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.ceil(2.01 * 10) / 10; //2.00
            //test greater value
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.ceil(2.16 * 10) / 10; //2.2
        } 
</script>
```